# Peoplesoft Learning Management - First Time Pass Rate

Tags: peoplesoft

We are working on PeopleSoft ELM 9.2 and I'm not finding what I need in any of the OOB queries so I'm attempting to build one. We need to get a "First Time Pass Rate" score, or the average of how many people pass a learning course on their first try. Ideally we would have the data for each attempt so that we could also see how many attempts a particular person or course has prior to getting a passing score.

Our setup includes SCORM 1.2 modules that pass off a score to the LMS for verification that a passing score was received. The closest I've been able to come so far is to get a "Pass/Fail" score but either my query unions are incorrect or the data is incorrect as it returns extraneous data that is not relevant to the other data returned or (if I force distinct values) it returns sporadically accurate data. Below is the SQL that I'm using if it helps.

Has anyone tried to build this kind of query before and how did you do it? :)

```
    SELECT DISTINCT  D1X.XLATLONGNAME, D.LM_ORGANIZATION_ID, D.LM_ORG_DESCR, 
D.LM_HR_EMPLID, TO_CHAR(D.LM_HIRE_DT,'YYYY-MM-DD'), D.FIRST_NAME, 
D.LAST_NAME, C.LM_CS_LONG_NM, C.LM_ACT_CD, A.LM_LC_LONG_NM, A.LM_LC_ID,  
B12X.XLATLONGNAME, TO_CHAR(B.LM_COMPL_DT,'YYYY-MM-DD'), B.LM_ENRLMT_ID,  
E15X.XLATLONGNAME 
    FROM PS_LM_LC A, PS_LM_ENRLMT B LEFT OUTER JOIN PSXLATITEM B12X ON 
B12X.FIELDNAME='LM_STTS' AND B12X.FIELDVALUE=B.LM_STTS AND B12X.EFF_STATUS = 
'A' AND B12X.EFFDT = (SELECT MAX(EFFDT) FROM PSXLATITEM TB WHERE 
TB.FIELDNAME=B12X.FIELDNAME AND TB.FIELDVALUE=B12X.FIELDVALUE AND  
TB.EFF_STATUS = 'A' AND TB.EFFDT <= TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'YYYY-MM-
DD'),'YYYY-MM-DD') ), PS_LM_ACT_CI_VW C, PS_LM_PERS_DTL_VW D LEFT OUTER JOIN 
PSXLATITEM D1X ON D1X.FIELDNAME='LM_ACTIVE' AND D1X.FIELDVALUE=D.LM_ACTIVE 
AND D1X.EFF_STATUS = 'A' AND D1X.EFFDT = (SELECT MAX(EFFDT) FROM PSXLATITEM 
TB WHERE TB.FIELDNAME=D1X.FIELDNAME AND TB.FIELDVALUE=D1X.FIELDVALUE AND  
TB.EFF_STATUS = 'A' AND TB.EFFDT <= TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'YYYY-MM-
DD'),'YYYY-MM-DD') ), PS_LM_ENR_LC_BL_VW E LEFT OUTER JOIN PSXLATITEM E15X 
ON E15X.FIELDNAME='LM_PASS_STTS' AND E15X.FIELDVALUE=E.LM_PASS_STTS AND 
E15X.EFF_STATUS = 'A' AND E15X.EFFDT = (SELECT MAX(EFFDT) FROM PSXLATITEM TB 
WHERE TB.FIELDNAME=E15X.FIELDNAME AND TB.FIELDVALUE=E15X.FIELDVALUE AND  
TB.EFF_STATUS = 'A' AND TB.EFFDT <= TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'YYYY-MM-
DD'),'YYYY-MM-DD') ) 
   WHERE ( A.LM_ACT_ID = B.LM_ACT_ID 
     AND A.LM_ACT_ID = C.LM_ACT_ID 
     AND D.LM_PERSON_ID = B.LM_PERSON_ID 
     AND D.BUSINESS_UNIT IN ('00340','00235') 
     AND B.LM_ENRL_DT BETWEEN TO_DATE(:1,'YYYY-MM-DD') AND TO_DATE(:2,'YYYY-MM-DD') 
 AND D.LM_HR_EMPLID = :3 
 AND D.LM_ACTIVE = :4 
 AND B.LM_STTS = 'COMP' 
 AND A.LM_LC_ID = E.LM_LC_ID 
 AND E.LM_PASS_STTS IN ('FAIL','PASS'))
```